# Makefile and main header file for a shell

Tags: c, git, posix, make

My `main.c` includes this header file. Please let me know how I can improve it. I did my best but I don't know much about code conventions in C (I come from Java and Python).

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500

#ifndef OPENSHELL_OPENSHELL_H
#define OPENSHELL_OPENSHELL_H
#define    CMD_LEN        1024
#define    EXPAND_ALLOC    1024
#define    PATH_LEN    1024
#define    isBlank(ch)    (((ch) == ' ') || ((ch) == '\t'))
#define    isDecimal(ch)    (((ch) >= '0') && ((ch) <= '9'))
#define    MAX_SOURCE    10
#define    isWildCard(ch)    (((ch) == '*') || ((ch) == '?') || ((ch) == '['))
#define    CHUNK_INIT_SIZE    4
#define    DEBUG TRUE
#ifndef VERSION
#define VERSION2 "v0.1a"
#endif

#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <utime.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <getopt.h>

/*
 * A chunk of data.
 * Chunks contain data which is allocated as needed, but which is
 * not freed until all of the data needs freeing, such as at
 * the beginning of the next command.
 */
typedef struct chunk CHUNK;

struct chunk {
    CHUNK *next;
    char data[CHUNK_INIT_SIZE];    /* actually of varying length */
};
/*
 * One entry of the command table.
 */
typedef struct {
    const char *name;

    int        (*func)(int argc, const char **argv);

    int minArgs;
    int maxArgs;
    const char *description;
    const char *usage;
} CommandEntry;

typedef int Pipe[2];

static struct option options[] = {
        {"with_param", 1, 0, 'p'},
        {"version",    0, 0, 'v'},
        {"help",       0, 0, 'h'},
        {0,            0, 0, 0}
};
struct command {
    char *const *argv;
};
extern void freeChunks(void);

extern char **str_split(char *a[], char *a_str, const char a_delim);

extern int do_checkenv(int argc, const char **argv);

extern int do_cd(int argc, const char **argv);

extern int do_add2path(int argc, const char **argv);

extern int do_exit(int argc, const char **argv);

extern int do_help(int argc, const char **argv);

extern int do_kill(int argc, const char **argv);

int spawn_proc(int in, int out, struct command *cmd);

void fork_pipes(int n, struct command *cmd);

int file_exist(char *filename);

extern bool makeArgs(const char *cmd, int *argcPtr, const char ***argvPtr, bool pipe, int g, int h);

#endif
#define VERSION "v0.160429-21-g54bb-dirty"
```

The above file is [versioned at github](https://github.com/montao/openshell/blob/c264cd4e268f29cf63fc5290c7794f66b0da5a69/openshell.h). You can also review the project's `Makefile`:

```
CC = gcc
GIT_VERSION := $(shell git describe --abbrev=4 --dirty --always --tags)
CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -L/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/include -pedantic -std=c99 -Wall -O3 -g -DVERSION=\"$(GIT_VERSION)\" -ledit -lncurses

LDIRS = -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib
LIBS =su -lcurses

shell: main.o
    $(CC) -o shell main.o errors.c util.c pipeline.c -ledit -lncurses -lcurses

main.o: main.c errors.c util.c
USERNAME := $(shell whoami >> username.txt)
GIT:= $(shell head -n -1 openshell.h > temp.txt ; mv temp.txt openshell.h;git describe --abbrev=4 --dirty --always --tags > VERSION; echo "\#define VERSION \"$(GIT_VERSION)\"" >> openshell.h)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

As seen in the `Makefile`, I'm writing the git version number to the header file with a shell instruction. Maybe I should do this before I compile to be able to get a "clean" version, otherwise I will always differ from a tag just by writing the new tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What is the header file's name?  The point being that the name of the header file, like `xopen.h` should have some connection to the items inside.  Further, the objects declares and macros defines are all over the name space.  Consider some convention. Put `do_...()` in `do.h`, `CommandEntry` in `CommandEntry.h`.
2. Strange `#define`.  Did you mean `#define VERSION "v0.1a"`?

   ```
   #ifndef VERSION
   //#define VERSION2 "v0.1a"
   #define VERSION "v0.1a"
   #endif
   ```
3. `static struct option options[]` will create a `options[]` with each *.c this include file is used.  Certainly not a good idea because it is `static`.  `static objects are best for the *.c file and not *.h header files.
4. Odd to have `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500` and `#define VERSION "v0.160429-21-g54bb-dirty"` outside the include guard `#ifndef OPENSHELL_OPENSHELL_H`.  Suggest putting them inside unless you are attempting something novel.
5. Line spacing is odd.  Why no line space after a `struct` definition, yet spaces between similar function declarations.

   ```
   struct command {
       char *const *argv;
   };
   extern void freeChunks(void);

   extern char **str_split(char *a[], char *a_str, const char a_delim);

   extern int do_checkenv(int argc, const char **argv);
   ```
6. The horizontal space is odd here - perhaps an effect of using tabs?

   ```
   #define    CMD_LEN        1024
   #define    EXPAND_ALLOC    1024
   #define    PATH_LEN    1024
   #define    isBlank(ch)    (((ch) == ' ') || ((ch) == '\t'))
   #define    isDecimal(ch)    (((ch) >= '0') && ((ch) <= '9'))
   #define    MAX_SOURCE    10
   ```
7. All UPPERCASE identifiers are often considered macros.  Code with `CHUNK` may confuse viewers of your code.  Re:`typedef struct chunk CHUNK;`
8. Not using all UPPERCASE for defines like with `#define isBlank(ch)` is a problem as a user of that macro does not benefit from the all uppercase hint that it *is* a macro.  That macro uses `ch` twice `(((ch) == ' ') || ((ch) == '\t'))`.  Consider the effect of this usage

   ```
   int ch;
   while (isBlank(ch = getchar())) { ... }
   ```
9. Standard suggestion.  Add name and date (year) to your code.

   ```
   // 2016 Programmer 400
   ```
10. C has a boolean `_Bool`.  By using `<stdbool.h>` , code has access to `bool`, `true`, `false`.  Suggest `true` rather than `TRUE` in `#define    DEBUG TRUE`.
11. Order:  In *general*, it is cleaner to do the `define` first, `struct, union, typedef`, then global variables and lastly function declaration.  This is highly a style issue though.
12. Unclear why some function have a preceding `extern` and others do not.  With function declarations, `extern` is not necessary.  To use or not is a style issue, but it should *certainly* be consistent within a *.h file.

    ```
    // to extern or not to extern, that is the question.  
    extern int do_kill(int argc, const char **argv);
    int spawn_proc(int in, int out, struct command *cmd);
    ```

Comment: Nice answer with lots of possibility for me to improve. Thank you! The name of the header file is `openshell.h` and it is my first non-trivial header file.

Comment: @Programmer 400 Welcome to C - programing without a net nor training wheels.